# SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel, I'm trying to convert my SQL into query builder in Laravel. But I got an error which is undefined column error.

my SQL:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS hour_stamp,
  (extract(hour FROM created_at)::int / 60) AS min_slot,
  count(*),
  max(e4) as kwh
FROM energydata_1001
WHERE api_key_value= 'YaB8JCcE'
AND date(created_at) >= '2020-11-30 23:59:59'
AND date(created_at) <= '2020-12-29 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

My query in Laravel:

```
$rnd = DB::table('energydata_1001')
            -> select (DB::raw("date_trunc('day',created_at) AS hour_stamp",
                               '(extract(hour FROM created_at)::int / 60) AS min_slot'),
                               'count(*)',
                               'max(e4) as kwh')
            ->where ('api_key_value', '=', 'YaB8JCcE')
            ->where ('date(created_at)', '>=', '2020-11-30 23:59:59')
            ->where ('date(created_at)', '<=', '2020-12-29 00:00:00')
            ->groupBy ('1, 2')
            ->orderBy ('1, 2')
            ->get();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. perhaps you are looking for the `whereDate` method for your date check against the `created_at` column .... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses